# Reaching out — Ballet West's Peter Christie helps fifth-graders learn to love dance

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Reaching out — Ballet West's Peter Christie helps fifth-graders learn to love dance.](https://www.deseretnews.com/article/685193195/Reaching-out--Ballet-Wests-Peter-Christie-helps-fifth-graders-learn-to-love-dance.html)

Q: In this sentence I think "Reaching out" means stretching your arm or your hand in order to touch or get something. What is your opinion?

Comment: It looks like a headline from a newspaper article. Newspapers often embed words with a  double meaning into headlines. In this case, “Reaching Out” could refer to a ballet movement as well as community service. But you don’t say where you found this, so I’m leaving a comment rather than a full-fledged answer. P.S. You might also be interested in the Stack Exchange’s community for [ell.se].

Comment: I got that sentence from google's this address. Please refer to it and I hope you expert will give the answer about my question.  https://www.deseretnews.com/article/685193195/Reaching-out--Ballet-Wests-Peter-Christie-helps-fifth-graders-learn-to-love-dance.html

Answer (score 0):

Newspaper headlines often embed puns related to the content of the article.

In the case of *Reaching Out*, that's a phrase that could mean a couple things:

- Literally, it means stretching out your arm – much like the woman is doing in the picture of the news article.
- Figuratively, it means offering some kind of assistance or aid, often in the form of community outreach.

The telecommunications giant Bell Telephone (now AT&T) once employed a long-time slogan which used a similar play on words:

> [Reach out and touch someone.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7BjQQ6SYDoo/maxresdefault.jpg)

The phrase *reach out and touch* suggests a literal meaning of the phrase, but, in the case of the phone company, it refers to reaching out (with a phone call) and touching someone (that is, touching their heart, by conveying a nice message).

In the news story you've cited, Peter Christie is reaching out to the community by teaching ballet, but the newspaper headline could have just as easily said:

> **Serving Others**: Ballet West's Peter Christie helps fifth-graders learn to love dance.

However, the clever double-meaning would have been lost.

Another possible phrase would have been:

> **Helping Hand**: Ballet West's Peter Christie helps fifth-graders learn to love dance.

However, that pun would put the focus on Christie's guiding hands, not the young ballerina's gracefully outstretched arm.

I think the editors got it right.

Comment: _"Extra! Extra! Read all about it!"_ As a footnote, you can read more about puns in newspaper headlines [here](https://www.courant.com/news/connecticut/hc-xpm-1992-06-21-0000200441-story.html).

Answer (score -1):

It's an idiomatic phrase.

reach out (to somebody):

> — phrasal verb with **reach**
>   to try to communicate with a person or a group of people, usually in order to help or involve them:
>   *The new mayor is reaching out to the local community to involve them in his plans for the city.*
>   ([cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reach-out-to-sb))